# deleting groups based on a condition from a dataframe - pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sym': list('aaaaaabb'), 'order': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'key': [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                   'vol': [1000, 1000, 500, 500, 100, 100, 200, 200]})
```

I add another column to it:

```
df['vol_cumsum'] = df.groupby(['sym', 'key', 'order']).vol.cumsum()
```

let`s define the problem like this (instead of words). Check this:

```
df.groupby(['sym', 'key', 'order']).vol_cumsum.last()
```

Now I want to omit the groups that their `vol_cumsum` ,according to the above groupby, do not match. In this case I want to omit the first group from my `df`.
My desired `df` looks like this:

```
4    3      0   a   100         100
5    3      1   a   100         100
6    4      0   b   200         200
7    4      1   b   200         200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) for `Series` with same size like original `DaatFrame`, then create nw column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html):

```
df['vol_cumsum'] = df.groupby(['sym', 'key', 'order']).vol.cumsum()
s = df.groupby(['sym', 'key', 'order']).vol_cumsum.transform('last')
mask = df.assign(new=df['vol_cumsum'].eq(s)).groupby(['sym', 'key', 'order'])['new'].transform('all')

df = df[mask]
print (df)
  sym  order  key  vol  vol_cumsum
4   a      0    3  100         100
5   a      1    3  100         100
6   b      0    4  200         200
7   b      1    4  200         200
```